# Google TV Media Source API

Tags: google-tv

On the Google TV developer site, there is a presentation from 2012 called "Streaming to Google TV" by Christian Kurzke (https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_presentations).  In this presentation, he describes a new API that enables developers to support custom streaming protocols (i.e. protocols other than HTTP Live Streaming, HTTP Progressive Streaming, etc).  The API is called the Media Source API.

For my Google TV app, I would like to use the Media Source API.  If I try to use any of the classes from the API, I receive compiler errors because the class is not found.  I have the Google TV add-on installed, but it does not appear to include this library.  My question is: where do I find the library jar file or source for the Media Source API and where can I find Javadoc documentation on it?  Other than the aforementioned presentation, I cannot find any other information about creating and building apps using this API.

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is internal API that was never officially released.  Maybe contacting the Devs directly they can provide access to it.

Comment: This appears to be the case, and I was afraid of that.  However given the number of documents on the Google TV developer site describing this and other APIs, I was hoping that I just wasn't looking in the right places.

Answer (score 0):

You have to contact the google tv directly in order to get access to these APIs.
However with GTV going towards 4.2.2, you can use the standard android APIs for achieving the same results.
The mediasource api was merely a layer that reproduced the media API from 4.+ and brought it to 3.2 on GTV platform.